# What is the name of this convex cone?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-geometry

For a nonnegative vector ${\bf w}=(w_1,\ldots,w_n)$, 
let $C_{\bf w}$ denote the convex cone of nonnegative vectors 
${\bf x}=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ such that 
$n \sum_{i=1}^n w_i x_i \geq \sum_{i=1}^n w_i \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \:$. 
In other words, the weighted average of $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ 
with weights $w_1,\ldots,w_n$ is greater or equal than the arithmetic average. 
Is there a name for this cone?

Comment: Half-space $H_{a}$ intersected with the first quadrant $\mathbb{R}^{n}_{+}$ seems to be a reasonable name for it, where $H_{a} :=\{  x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}\,  : x \cdot a \geq 0\}$, $a = (\tilde{w}_{1}-1/n, ..., \tilde{w}_{n}-1/n)$, and $\tilde{w_{j}} = \frac{w_{j}}{\sum w_{j}}$.